# Thumbs up gem routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, vote

I seek clarification on using the thumbs up gem with rails 4. I current have a user resource and a post resource and have set up thumbs up as follows.

add gem to gemfile and installed it using bundler.
Generated require migration

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 acts_as_voter
end
```

Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 acts_as_voteable
end
```

Post controller

```
def vote_up
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 current_user.vote_for(@post)
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js
 end
end
```

View

```
<%= link_to('vote for this post!', vote_up_post_path(@post) , :method => :post) %>
```

Route file

```
resources :posts do
  member do
   post :vote_up
  end
 end
```

However i keep getting this error

```
No route matches [POST] "/posts/vote_up"
```

And after running rake routes I can see that the following route is available to me:

```
vote_up_post POST   /posts/:id/vote_up(.:format) posts#vote_up
```

any ideas what could be the cause of this error ?

Comment: Could you add your view?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show us your view.

Apparently, you are calling

```
/posts/vote_up
```

instead of

```
/posts/:id/vote_up
```

Answer (score 0):

"vote_up" acts like a RESTful action, similar to "post/1/delete", "post/1/edit". So you need to add this custom RESTful action in route.

Change your route like this at first.

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    post 'vote_up'
  end
end
```

Then, in your view, to use this path, add resource as arg

```
vote_up_post_path @post
```

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: Sorry i did not include my route setup in my original post. It was already set up like that.

Comment: @Joshua, everything seems legit. Have you tried to restart rails server after route change?

Answer (score 0):

Other people reading this notes should realise that post is not a singluar of his controller posts... but the post http verb

```
resources :contenders do
  member do
   post 'vote_up'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but in your view, instead of @post try giving @post.id to vote_up_post_path.

```
<%= link_to('vote for this post!', vote_up_post_path(@post.id) , :method => :post) %>
```